# I can't get CSS drop-down menu work

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu, positioning

When I hover my mouse over the dropdown menu, it just doesn't appear, nothing happens, like the whole thing is missing ..

```
#menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    height:25px;
    background: rgb(38, 42, 53);
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(38, 42, 53, 1) 0%, rgba(40, 45, 63, 1) 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(38, 42, 53, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(40, 45, 63, 1)));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(38, 42, 53, 1) 0%, rgba(40, 45, 63, 1) 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(38, 42, 53, 1) 0%, rgba(40, 45, 63, 1) 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(38, 42, 53, 1) 0%, rgba(40, 45, 63, 1) 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(38, 42, 53, 1) 0%, rgba(40, 45, 63, 1) 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#262a35', endColorstr='#282d3f', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-9 */
}
ul#menu {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 15px;
}
ul#menu li {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:3px 10px 0 70px;
}
ul#menu li a {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    color:#84FD00;
    /* #874B46 */
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:0;
    height:12px;
}
ul#menu li ul {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top:50px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow:none;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
ul#menu li ul li {
    background: #555;
    dipslay: inline;
    color: #fff;
}
ul#menu li ul li:hover {
    background: #666;
}
ul#menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

The code is a mix-up of 2 codes, maybe I didn't get it right. Only the drop-down part is not working(where the ul#menu li ul thing is).

The HTML code:

```
<ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="index.php">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="forum.php">Forum</a></li>
            <li><a href="Demos.php">Demos</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="demos.php">Recorded demos</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="Rules.php">Rules</a></li>
            <li><a href="Administration.php">Administration</a></li>
            <li><a href="search.php">Search</a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Can you post your html code please?

Comment: Your top element "#menu" has a height of 12px and overflow of auto... without seeing the html, i can only guess that anything inside of the container will be hidden.

Comment: Well, I guess the overflow is the problem, but when I remove it, the menu background bar goes upwards replacing my header

Comment: That will be up to you to make sure the css styles are working the way you want.  but that was the main problem you had... see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the top element "#menu" has a height of 25px and overflow of auto... this is causing everything to be hidden.

Try adding this css:

```
ul#menu:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

and delete the property that says `overflow:auto;` <--- (edit: sorry I typed the wrong thing earlier)

You will see the drop menu appear.

Basically this solution will cause the floats to clear themselves without using overflow auto.

Bonus:

Add `position: relative;` to your `ul#menu li` and the dropdown will start to line up better with your top level navigation.

I'll leave the rest up to you :)

Comment: Thanks very much, the last part was essential as well :)

Comment: Oh, i was correcting in the jsbin and you have answered it before me :P

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/pezuk/1)**

The main error is because, you have overflow: auto; in the #menu.

i have made some more changes, this css will fix the issues

```
#menu {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height:25px;
    background: rgb(38, 42, 53);
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(38, 42, 53, 1) 0%, rgba(40, 45, 63, 1) 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(38, 42, 53, 1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(40, 45, 63, 1)));
    /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(38, 42, 53, 1) 0%, rgba(40, 45, 63, 1) 100%);
    /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(38, 42, 53, 1) 0%, rgba(40, 45, 63, 1) 100%);
    /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(38, 42, 53, 1) 0%, rgba(40, 45, 63, 1) 100%);
    /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(38, 42, 53, 1) 0%, rgba(40, 45, 63, 1) 100%);
    /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#262a35', endColorstr='#282d3f', GradientType=0);
    /* IE6-9 */
}
ul#menu {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 15px;
}
ul#menu li {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    margin:0;
    padding:3px 10px 0 70px;
   postition: relative;
}
ul#menu li a {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    color:#84FD00;
    /* #874B46 */
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:0;
    height:12px;
}
ul#menu li ul {
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top:50px;
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow:none;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
ul#menu li ul li {
  background: #555;
color: #fff;
padding-left: 0px;
padding: 10px 10px;
}
ul#menu li ul li:hover {
    background: #666;
}
ul#menu li:hover ul {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
   padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top:25px;
    height: auto;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: but below that he has a hover that will cause it to be visible with opacity of 1

Answer (score 0):

u can use this structure for ur code and style over it

CSS:

```
*{padding:0;margin:0;}

ul#menu li {
    position:relative;
    list-style-type:none;
    float: left;
    padding:0px;
    width: 125px;
    height: 25px;
}
ul#sub1 {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    width:125px;
    visibility: hidden;
    display:none;
}
ul#menu li:hover #sub1 {
    display:block;
    visibility:visible;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 2</a>

        <ul id="sub1">
            <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 2.1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 2.2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Hyperlink 4</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```